# Symfony3: how to invoke a custom twig function in a twig template?

Tags: twig, symfony-3.4

I have a main twig template same as below:

```
# main.html.twig

{% block main %}
{{ layout|raw }}
{% endblock %}
```

in variable of layout, where has a custom twig function: customFunction that is a html code:

> #### title
>
> there has some text

But now, when I render the main.html.twig:

```
{{ customFunction(4) }}
```

not is:

```
<h3>title</h3><p>there has some text</p>
```

how to solve it?

Comment: Watch my answer on the topic here above

Comment: @DarkBee thanks for your reply.